# OOP Design: Is it OK to place uncommon method in parent class, if most of subclasses have it?

Tags: java, oop

There are 10 classes that have method `orderId()` and 2 that don't.

All of the messages are subclasses of class called `Message`.

Should the parent class `Messages` still have a `setOrderId(String value)` method to implement that logic all in one place?

My problem is that if I won't do that then I'll have to use concrete class to use that method!

Comment: Implement an Orderable interface. ```extends Messages implements Orderable```.

Comment: A message class shouldn't have a parent class called `Messages` - the plural implies that it models multiple messages.

Comment: OP, correct me if I changed something important in your question

Comment: It is not clear why do you need to use this specific method on parent class objects. If not all messages have orderId, maybe you should change your design.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for the feedback I made that change its not Message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement `setOrderId()` on the common superclass, then as a result, *all* of the subclasses have that property (even if some provide no getter).  If that is inappropriate / unfitting then no, it is not good design.

> My problem is that if I do not do that then I need to subclass if programming to an interface each time I want to use that method!

Perhaps you need an interface that most of the subclasses implement, or an intermediate superclass for them, that provides the `setOrderId()` method, and presumably also `orderId()`.  When you are passing objects to a method that expects to be able to access the `orderId` property, use the common interface or class that provides it as the argument type.

Answer (score 0):

Create abstract class that has all common methods (AbstractMessage), create subclass that has orderId() method (OrderMessage), create another one without this method (Message).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement setOrderld() in the parent class, and then override the method in the objects that don't have setOrderld() to do nothing. Then you would have to remember to override in the objects that don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The Messages class could have a default `setOrderId(String value)` method that any subclass can override or extend if necessary. For example:

```
class Message {
    String orderId;

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
}
```

Then you could subclass this as many times as required:

```
class RestrictedMessage {

    @Override
    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        if (orderId.length > 0) {
            super.setOrderId(orderId);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can override but still use the original functionality if desired.